# stanford-nlp ignore text in sentence or ignore sentence identifier

Tags: java, vb.net, stanford-nlp

I am doing **chat analysis**.  I pre-process each sentence in a conversation and store it in a database. The conversation has a unique key and each sentence has it's own key.  When I load a conversation into the pipeline to annotate it (see code below, vb.net) how can I keep track of the sentences after the annotation?

I tried to include a key in the first part of each sentence (Example: _125678 is the sentence key) but the parser identifies it as a Noun Phrase.  Can I tell the parser to **ignore my database keys**? Perhaps by surrounding it with some special characters? Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
' Path to the folder with models extracted from `stanford-corenlp-3.4-models.jar`
        Dim jarRoot = "stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models"

    'when the annotation is complete I want the output to include the database keys (like 125678) so I can link this line back to the conversation
    Dim txt As String = "_125678 This movie doesn't care about cleverness, wit or any other kind of intelligent humor. Those who find ugly meanings in beautiful things are corrupt without being charming. There are slow and repetitive parts, but it has just enough spice to keep it interesting."

    ' Annotation pipeline configuration
    Dim props = New Properties()
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref, sentiment")
    props.setProperty("sutime.binders", "0")
    props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "0")

    ' We should change current directory, so StanfordCoreNLP could find all the model files automatically 
    Dim curDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("") ' Environment.CurrentDirectory

    Try
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(curDir & "\" & jarRoot)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The specified directory does not exist. {0}", ex)
    End Try

    ' Annotation
    Dim annotation = New Annotation(txt)

    Dim pipeline = New StanfordCoreNLP(props)

    Try
        pipeline.annotate(annotation)

        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(curDir)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The specified directory does not exist. {0}", ex)
    End Try


    ' these are all the sentences in this document
    ' a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
    Dim sentences = annotation.[get](GetType(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation))
    'Dim tokens = annotation.[get](GetType(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation))


    Dim mainSentiment As String = String.Empty
    Dim longest As Integer = 0

    For Each sentence As Annotation In TryCast(sentences, ArrayList)
        nlp = nlp & sentence.toString
        nlp = nlp & "<br/>"

        Dim tree As Tree = sentence.[get](GetType(edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree))
        Dim sentiment As Integer = edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree)

        'get noun phrases from tree
        'getNounPhrases(tree)

        'dependency parser, shows you the top themes in a sentence
        'Dim depparse As Tree = sentence.[get](GetType(edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser))
        'Dim depparse_result As Integer = edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap(tree)

        Dim partText As String = sentence.toString()
        If partText.Length > longest Then

            Select Case sentiment
                Case 0
                    mainSentiment = "<span class='btn btn-danger'>0. Very Negative</span>"
                Case 1
                    mainSentiment = "<span class='btn btn-warning'>1. Negative</span>"
                Case 2
                    mainSentiment = "<span class='btn btn-info'>2. Neutral</span>"
                Case 3
                    mainSentiment = "<span class='btn btn-primary'>3. Positive</span>"
                Case 4
                    mainSentiment = "<span class='btn btn-success'>4. Very Positive</span>"
            End Select

            'find the suggested main subjects for each line of text
            nlp = nlp & "(SENTIMENT):<br/>" & mainSentiment & "<br/><br/>(NOUN PHRASE/SUBJECT):<br/>"
            Dim arr As Array = Split(getNounPhrases(tree), "|", -1)
            For Each s As String In arr
                nlp = nlp & s.ToString & "<br/>"
            Next

            'NER (Named Entity Recognition) 
            'Recognizes named (PERSON, LOCATION, ORGANIZATION, MISC), numerical (MONEY, NUMBER, ORDINAL, PERCENT), and temporal (DATE, TIME, DURATION, SET) entities.

            Dim myNer As String = ner(sentence.toString)
            If myNer.Length > 1 Then
                nlp = nlp & "(NAMED ENTITY RECOGNITION):<br/>" & myNer
            End If


            nlp = nlp & "<hr>"

        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) strip off the conversationID from the string before building the annotation

2.) set the docID:

```
annotation = new Annotation(txt);
annotation.set(CoreAnnotations.DocIDAnnotation.class, "125678");
```

3.) after annotation, the sentences will have the docID, and be indexed by their order in the "doc" (i.e. a conversation)

To access the conversation id:

```
sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.DocIDAnnotation.class);
```

To access the sentence id within the conversation:

```
sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.SentenceIndexAnnotation.class);
```